# Why Autoprefixer doesn't add prefix for font-smoothing

Tags: webpack, autoprefixer

`Autoprefixer` webpack loader adding autoprefix for all css however it doesn't add autoprefix for `font-smoothing : antialiased`.

why it's not adding autoprefix for this?

Answer (score 5):

I guess because it is an vendor (-webkit-) specific attribute. So there are no other prefixes with this attribute. You can see a little discussion on twitter as well: https://twitter.com/autoprefixer/status/444429500789841921?lang=nl

Found another website who explain the usage more: 
https://davidwalsh.name/font-smoothing

TL;DR:

For other vendors you even need another setting (antialiased and grayscale)

```
.element {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```